# Keyset pagination with multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

I'm trying to do keyset pagination with multiple columns but I can't get it to work on any page except the first one. Also one of the columns in the keyset columns is nullable (`col1`) and sorted with `nulls last`.

```
select colId, col1, col2 from tablename
where (case when parameter_col1 is null then true else col1 < parameter_col1)
and (case when parameter_col2 is null then true else col2 < parameter_col2)
and (case when parameter_colId is null then true else colId < parameter_colId)
order by col1 desc nulls last, col2 desc, colId desc
limit 10;
```

I'm using these `case` statements in each `where` so that on the first page of results when `null` is passed in for all 3 `parameter_` values, then everything is returned. So it works fine on the first page of results.

But on the second page it doesn't return the right results whether or not `parameter_col1` is null. What is the right way to do pagination with multiple columns (where some of them can be null)?

Would it help to break it into 2 separate queries, 1 for the first page and another for all subsequent queries? I'd prefer to combine it into a single query for easier maintenance if possible, but if not I can put both queries into a function of type `sql` or `plpgsql` so they're at least in the same place, and use an `if` to choose which one to use.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can you show what it should look like?

Comment: `(parameter_col1 is null OR col1 < parameter_col1)`

Comment: Reading tip: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: Could I rewrite this type of where clause using and/or? `where col = case when param is null then col else param`

Comment: Write a query to get the correct result with non-NULL parameters first, then worry about consolidating it with the first-page query later.  (Or Never)

Answer (score 0):

Pick a value that is less than all possible `col1` values and use that with `coalesce`. For example, if `col1` is of type `timestamp`, you could use `'-infinity'`, and the query would look like

```
SELECT colId, col1, col2 from tablename
WHERE ROW(coalesce(col1, '-infinity'), col2, colId)
    < ROW(coalesce(parameter_col1, 'infinity'), parameter_col2, parameter_colId)
ORDER BY coalesce(col1, '-infinity') DESC, col2 DESC, colid DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

That could be fast with an index on the `ORDER BY` expression.

Comment: In postgres pagination examples I always see a single `WHERE` with a single `<` or `>`. Is it necessary to do it this way or is this `ROW` syntax just a simpler way of writing it if your `ORDER BY` is all `ASC` or all `DESC` columns? Because if some columns are `ASC` and some are `DESC` then you can't use `ROW` and would have to use `WHERE` with multiple `AND`?

Comment: If you don't compare like this, you cannot use a (multi-column) index.

Comment: The second page of results is giving the exact same as the first page of results. When `parameter_col1` is `null` and `parameter_col2` is not `null` (second page of results), it gives the same as when both are `null` (first page of results). I gave a simplified example in the question but in practice `col2` is coming from a `inner join` table. That probably makes an index not possible but your answer should still work. Do you know why it's same result on second page?

Comment: @user779159 You can't be running Laurenz's query exactly, as it has syntax errors.  Please edit our question to show the exact query you ran.